# Webcam / Video Playback Problems in Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: drivers, video, webcam, media, ubuntu-mate

I have tried both Cheese and guvcview. The vids play back fine in the recording apps themselves, but when I load them up in VLC, OpenShot, or Cinelerra, all I get is the initial frame (frozen) and the audio track.

I have tried both .mkv and .avi formats in guvcview (Cheese only allows .mkv), and I get the same result every time. I have also tried converting to .mp4 - When I do this, I get no picture at all, and only audio.

My laptop is an HP dv7 4285-dx, and the webcam I'm using is the built-in HP TrueVision located in the center above the screen. I'm running kernel 4.2.0-25-generic x86_64.

Another problem I'm having is that this webcam should be able to go above 640 x 480 resolution, but I can't seem to find the option in any of the recording apps, nor can I find the proprietary drivers anywhere online.

If you need more info, comment and I will provide to the best of my ability. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is one of the files (.avi), which is doing the same thing.

http://www.datafilehost.com/d/0bd39092

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Could you upload one of the created videos (that don't play on vlc) here: http://www.datafilehost.com/ . Interesting to see if the files themselves are unusual in any way...

Comment: Done. http://www.datafilehost.com/d/0bd39092

Comment: Thanks for that. FFprobe reports a problem with that file: 'scale/rate is 1000/0 which is invalid. (This file has been generated by broken software.)' and the video does not play on my system, audio is fine. A few thoughts: 1. Small update available from the developer's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~pj-assis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  2. Have a look at the file `~/.config/guvciew `to alter video resolution, fps and others. 3. I believe guvcview uses FFmpeg for output video so it might be worth your while to use a more modern FFmpeg, I cannot test this at the moment as my own webcam is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:

**sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**

Open **Synaptic package mananger** from Mate menu and search for **ubuntu-drivers-common** & **software-properties-gtk** and make sure that both are installed if not just **right click** on it and choose **Mark for installation** and **Apply**.

Now open the **Mate menu** then look for **Additional Drivers** then choose the proprietary driver for your graphics card, if is marked as **tested** enable that. Now reboot.

If you cant find the Additional Drivers for Mate menu just type in a terminal:

**/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4**

OR

**software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4**

OR

**software-properties-gtk**

I never used the Mate distro in the past.